# How do I open syncfusion report viewer without reportpath

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, reportviewer, syncfusion

I have RDL content in DB. So based on reportID i can render the DB content. 
I dont want to add physical file in system , Since Reportviewer looking for reportpath how can achieve this?

Directly show the report viewer with string of RDL content

Since the API are confidential not able to view the desired method to override.

aspx page:

code behind:

```
string targetFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + @"Report Templates\ReportViewer\";
string reportPath = targetFolder + @"\" + reportDefID + ".rdl";

deDesign oDE = new deDesign();
deReportDefinition oDef = oDE.getReportDefinition(reportDefID);
string sXML = oDef.export();

Hashtable oProps = oDef.getProperties("REPORTNAME");
lblReportName.Text = oProps["REPORTNAME"].ToString();

File.WriteAllText(reportPath, sXML);
viewer.ReportPath = reportPath;

lblStatus.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sXML) ? "No Data Found" : "";
dvReportViewer.Visible = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sXML) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can achieve your requirement by passing as FileStream to Syncfusion ReportViewer instead of ReportPath. Please find the snippet handled in controller side below,

```
public class ReportApiController : ApiController, IReportController 
{ 
    public object PostReportAction(Dictionary<string, object> jsonResult) 
    { 
        return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonResult, this); 
    } 

    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("GetResource")] 
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")] 
    public object GetResource(string key, string resourcetype, bool isPrint) 
    { 
        return ReportHelper.GetResource(key, resourcetype, isPrint); 
    } 

    public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption) 
    { 
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/GroupingAgg.rdl"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
        reportOption.ReportModel.Stream = fs; 
    } 

    public void OnReportLoaded(ReportViewerOptions reportOption) 
    { 

    } 
}
```

Please find the sample reference below which will assist your requirement,

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReportviewerSample141241572.zip

**Note**: In the above sample, we have read the physical path file as stream and loaded it. You can modify the sample as per your needs to pass the xml content as FileStream.